# Not able to create directory or file in php using @fopen

Tags: php

I am Trying to create a directory but whenever I try to call it. Nothing is happening. Do not know why this is happening please assist.

```
$year = date('Y');
$month = date('m');
$date = date('d');

$randomString = substr( md5(uniqid (rand())), 0, 10);
$content = $videos;
$k = strlen($content);
$f = $website.'cdn/up3/video/'.$year.'/'.$month.'/'.$date.'/'.$productId.'-'.$randomString.'.mp4';

$hFile = @fopen($f, 'wb');
$m = @fwrite($hFile, $content, $k);
@fclose($f);
```

Comment: start by removing the `@` error suppressors and use error reporting.

Comment: then come back to edit your post and show us what those errors are. You can also @Fred me if you want direct assistance.

Comment: "I am Trying to create a directory" Where exactly are you trying to do that? I see you trying to open (and create if it doesn't exists) a _file_, but that doesn't create any _directories_.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the permission of the folder where you are creating the file. It should be 755, if it is no use the below code:

```
chmod("your folder path", 755);
```